# inherit function that is inside scope to another function

Tags: javascript, scope

I want to get the return value of validatePassword() and validate() function outside its scope. Those values should be returned inside the function firstNextButton(). If both input fields are validated right, the button must be clickable, which means that the attribute disabled will be removed inside the element.

```js
(function validationPassword() {
        var inputPassWord = document.getElementById('inputpassword');
        var passErrorMessage = document.getElementById('password-error');
        
        function validatePassword() {
            var inputPasswordValue = inputPassWord.value;
            
            if(inputPasswordValue.length > 0) {
                passErrorMessage.innerHTML = "Password correct";
            } else {
                passErrorMessage.innerHTML = "Password incorrect";
            }
        }

        inputPassWord.onblur = function() {
            firstNextButton();
        }
    })();

    (function validationEmail() {
        var emailInput = document.getElementById('email');
        var emailError = document.getElementById('email-error');
        var email = emailInput.value;

        function validateEmail(email) {
            var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            return re.test(email);
        }

        function validate() {
            if(validateEmail(email)) {
                emailError.innerHTML = 'Email is correct';
            }
            else {
                emailError.innerHTML = 'mail not correct. Example: name@gmail.com';
            }
            return false;
        }    

        emailInput.onblur = function() {
            emailvalidate;
            firstNextButton();
        }
    })();

    function firstNextButton() {
        var firstButton = document.getElementById('firstStepButton');
        console.log('hello firstNextButton');

        // if(validate() && validatePassword()) {
        //     console.log('hello world');
        //     firstButton.removeAttribute('disabled', '');
        // } else {
        //     firstButton.setAttribute('disabled', '');
        // }
    }
```

```html
<div class="form-block">
      <div class="required-field">
          <label class="control-label">Email Address</label>
          <input name="email" id="email" class="form-control contact-input" type="email" placeholder="<?= $this->lang->line('application_email_address') ?>" required>

          <span id="email-error"></span>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-block">
      <div class="required-field">
          <label class="control-label">Password</label>
          <input name="password" id="inputpassword" class="form-control contact-input" type="password" placeholder="<?= $this->lang->line('application_password') ?>" required>
          <span id="password-error"></span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div>
  
    <button class="btn btn-info btn-round nextBtn pull-right" id="firstStepButton" type="button">Sign Up</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solely answer your question, you can return the functions you need like this :

```js
var validationPassword = (function validationPassword() {
  var inputPassWord = document.getElementById('inputpassword');
  var passErrorMessage = document.getElementById('password-error');

  function validatePassword() {
    var inputPasswordValue = inputPassWord.value;

    if (inputPasswordValue.length > 0) {
      passErrorMessage.innerHTML = "Password correct";
    } else {
      passErrorMessage.innerHTML = "Password incorrect";
    }
  }

  inputPassWord.onblur = function() {
    firstNextButton();
  }
  
  return {
    validatePassword: validatePassword
  };
})();

var validationEmail = (function validationEmail() {
  var emailInput = document.getElementById('email');
  var emailError = document.getElementById('email-error');
  var email = emailInput.value;

  function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
  }

  function validate() {
    if (validateEmail(email)) {
      emailError.innerHTML = 'Email is correct';
    } else {
      emailError.innerHTML = 'mail not correct. Example: name@gmail.com';
    }
    return false;
  }

  emailInput.onblur = function() {
    validate();
    firstNextButton();
  }
  
  return {
    validate: validate
  };
})();

function firstNextButton() {
  var firstButton = document.getElementById('firstStepButton');
  
  if(validationEmail.validate() && validationPassword.validatePassword()) {
       console.log('hello world');
       firstButton.removeAttribute('disabled', '');
  } else {
       firstButton.setAttribute('disabled', '');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-block">
  <div class="required-field">
    <label class="control-label">Email Address</label>
    <input name="email" id="email" class="form-control contact-input" type="email" placeholder="<?= $this->lang->line('application_email_address') ?>" required>

    <span id="email-error"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-block">
  <div class="required-field">
    <label class="control-label">Password</label>
    <input name="password" id="inputpassword" class="form-control contact-input" type="password" placeholder="<?= $this->lang->line('application_password') ?>" required>
    <span id="password-error"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div>

  <button class="btn btn-info btn-round nextBtn pull-right" id="firstStepButton" type="button">Sign Up</button>
</div>
```

Or refactor your code and take them outside the modules scopes.

As a side note, you forgot the parenthesis in `emailInput.onblur` function (and gave it the wrong name, too) :

```
emailInput.onblur = function() {
    validate(); // <---- Here
    firstNextButton();
}
```

Also, you don't call `validePassword` inside the `onblur` event, and you don't take the value of the input you're trying to validate. Add something like `email = emailInput.value;` inside the top of the `validate` function.

Comment: No matter if both input fields are correct, the returned value is still false....

Comment: @ncxcnb You should read my entire answer, I suggested you to improve your code by adding `email = emailInput.value;` into your `validate` function, for example.

Comment: validationEmail.validate():false, 
               validationPassword.validatePassword():undefined

Comment: @ncxcnb Did you wondered why `validationPassword.validatePassword()` _**returns**_ `undefined` ? Did you changed anything in the `validate` function ?

Comment: sorry I overlooked something, set the if else statement always to false. Stupidity.

Comment: But now it returns the password and email at the same time.

Comment: @ncxcnb Yes, because both of your `onblur` functions call `firstNextButton` which itself calls the two validations methods...

Comment: Yes I did that on purpose, but the error message of password is showing up when I onblur the email input field. The onblur function should be called when someone click outside the focused input field.

Comment: @ncxnb Yes, because both of your `onblur` functions call `firstNextButton` which itself calls the two validations methods which themselves show errors messages...

Comment: Is there a way to get the value without calling the function itself?

Comment: No , you can't.